# Python google maps - geocoding

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm a begginer in the Python programming (I do GIS system what supports Python) and I need to do geocoding.
I downloaded this library and I have already installed it from python-gmaps in version 0.3.1 - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gmaps/0.3.1#downloads.

Does anyone know what I have to add to the code to run it correctly?
There is a "problem" with "self" - Where I have to write it?
I need in the input the address and on output it will write the coordinates.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from gmaps.client import Client

class Geocoding(Client):

    GEOCODE_URL = "geocode/"
    print("Here")
    def geocode(self, address, components, region, language, bounds, sensor):
        parameters = dict(
            address=address,
            components=components,
            language=language,
            sensor=sensor,
            region=region,

        )
        if bounds:
            parameters['bounds'] = "%f,%f|%f,%f" % (
                bounds[0][0], bounds[0][1], bounds[1][0], bounds[1][1])
        return self._make_request(self.GEOCODE_URL, parameters, "results")
    geocode(self, "London", None, None,None, None, None)
```

Comment: There is no `self.GEOCODE_URL`. You haven't provided the traceback (which you should include so we can see the actual error - "problem" isn't helpful), but that will cause one issue: either remove `self` from `GEOCODE_URL` or add it at the top e.g.  `self.GEOCODE_URL = "geocode/"`

Comment: Also, I don't know the library but methods named with a single leading underscore (`_make_request`) generally indicates that you probably shouldn't be using them directly. Are you sure this is how to use the API?

Comment: Unless you are going to be having different GEOCODE_URL variables for each instance do you really need to use self

Comment: Pending a specific answer for your question, you might be interested in reading [this](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) as it's a great, compact intro to classes. That will explain `self` and other things that are general to Python.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Geocoding RESTful API is much simpler. Here's the code to resolve your issue:
    import requests
    import json

```
address = "London"
apiKey = "Your-API-Key"

r = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+ address +"&key="+ apiKey)
d = json.loads(r.content)
print d['results'][0]['geometry']['bounds']
```